# Border out (not IN) of custom annotation swift when tapped

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, geometry, mkannotationview

When custom my annotation view (Pin) in MapView was tapped, I need in white border OUT of my annotation.

[image: (left - tapped, right - not tapped]

Also I need in shadow, when tapped. But how could I make it? (when I deselect annotation have to stay right style). If I make it with:

var newFrame: CGRect = view.frame; newFrame = newFrame.insetBy(dx: -borderWidth, dy: -borderWidth); view.frame = newFrame; in mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) method and set border - my image will enlarge too, but it isn't right.

```
// My custom annotation
class CustomPointAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var restoInfo: Restaurant?

    init(resto: Restaurant) {
        self.coordinate = resto.coordinate!
        self.restoInfo = resto
    }
}

// And func adding custom annotation on MapView
var restorationPin: CustomPointAnnotation!
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?
{
    let cpa = annotation as? CustomPointAnnotation
    if cpa?.restoInfo == nil {
        return nil
    }

    let annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: restorationPin, reuseIdentifier: "id")

    let icon = cpa?.restoInfo?.encodeBase64toImage(base64: (cpa?.restoInfo?.logoMap)!)

    annotationView.image = icon
    annotationView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    annotationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    annotationView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 45, height: 45)
    annotationView.layer.cornerRadius = 22.5
    return annotationView
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into mapView `didSelect` and `didDeselect` MKAnnotationView methods from `MKMapViewDelegate`?

Comment: It’s empty now. I haven’t any ideas how make it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you implement the following two methods to detect when an annotation is selected/deselected, you can draw/remove a white circle as a `UIView` beneath your annotation. First in your view controller, set the `mapView`'s delegate.

```
self.mapView.delegate = self
```

Beneath are the two methods to detect when an annotation is clicked.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    /*Make a white circle*/
    let whiteBackground = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: -27, y: -55, width: 80, height: 80))
    whiteBackground.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    whiteBackground.layer.cornerRadius = 40

    /*Set circle's tag to 1*/
    whiteBackground.tag = 1
    /*Add the circle beneath the annotation*/
    view.insertSubview(whiteBackground, at: 0)
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didDeselect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    /*Removing the white circle*/
    view.viewWithTag(1)?.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Explanation. When an annotation is clicked, the `didSelect` method is called, and a white circle is created from a `UIView`. *This white circle view has a tag of `1` for convenience when it needs to be removed*. Then this view will be inserted as a subview having the annotation's view as the superview at index zero to make it be shown behind the annotation. The `didDeselect` method removes the circle by referencing the tag.

Personally, you're better off just inserting a white circle as an `UIImageView` instead of making a circle from a `UIView`, as it's less *hack-ish*.

**Demo**

[image: Map Annotation with white circle]